# Pguc coin transfer to address of bitcoin by mistake

Tags: transactions, recover-private-key

I have an account registered with PGUC. In the spend wallet they ask for the exchange address where to transfer the coins. What happened I need to transfer these coins in Pguc address but by mistake I send to Bitcoin address. My coins disappear from the wallet. Can I recover that coin ?